Adding a swipe gestures for a word search game/activity
I tried adding swipe gestures for the game, so that i don't always have to click the words letter by letter. I find it easier to just swipe across the whole word. Could anyone help me. I'm new to stack overflow and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to send code here. In the "What did you try and what were you expecting" segment i added part of the code. Let me know if i need to add the "GridAdapter.kt" code too.
private val rows = 10
    private val cols = 8
    private val letters = Array(rows) { CharArray(cols) { ' ' } }
    private val selectedLetters = mutableSetOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()
    private val foundWords = mutableSetOf<String>()
    private var wordsPlaced: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    private var hintIndex = 0

    private var startX = -1
    private var startY = -1
    private var currentX = -1
    private var currentY = -1

    private var swiping = false

    private val wordsToFind = listOf(
        "FAMILY", "FUN", "HAPPY", "SUN", "CAT", "DOG", "HOUSE", "CAR", "TREE", "MOON",
        "STAR", "BIRD", "BOOK", "CHAIR", "TABLE", "WATER", "FISH", "SHOE", "APPLE", "GRAPE",
        "PLANE", "BOAT", "TRAIN", "CUP", "MILK", "KEY", "DOOR", "CLOCK", "PENCIL", "PAPER",
        "PHONE", "BAG", "FORK", "SPOON", "CHAIR", "BED", "WINDOW", "HAT", "COAT", "BALL",
        "BEAR", "HORSE", "FROG", "FOX", "LION", "MOUSE", "COW", "PIG", "SHEEP", "ZEBRA"
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_search)

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView)
        wordListColumn1 = findViewById(R.id.wordListColumn1)
        wordListColumn2 = findViewById(R.id.wordListColumn2)
        resetButton = findViewById(R.id.resetButton)
        hintButton = findViewById(R.id.hintButton)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        progressText = findViewById(R.id.progressText)
        timerText = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)
        roundMessage = findViewById(R.id.roundMessage)

        setUpGrid()

        resetButton.setOnClickListener {
            setUpGrid()
        }

        hintButton.setOnClickListener {
            provideHint()
        }

        gridView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            handleTouch(event)
            true
        }
    }

    private fun handleTouch(event: MotionEvent) {
        val cellWidth = gridView.width / cols
        val cellHeight = gridView.height / rows

        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                startX = (event.x / cellWidth).toInt().coerceIn(0, cols - 1)
                startY = (event.y / cellHeight).toInt().coerceIn(0, rows - 1)
                Log.d("WordSearch", "Action Down: StartX: $startX, StartY: $startY")
                selectedLetters.clear()
                selectedLetters.add(startY to startX)
                swiping = true
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (swiping) {
                    currentX = (event.x / cellWidth).toInt().coerceIn(0, cols - 1)
                    currentY = (event.y / cellHeight).toInt().coerceIn(0, rows - 1)
                    Log.d("WordSearch", "Action Move: CurrentX: $currentX, CurrentY: $currentY")

                    if (isValidSwipe(startX, startY, currentX, currentY)) {
                        updateSelectedLetters(startX, startY, currentX, currentY)
                    }

                    // Visual indication of the swiping action
                    val gridAdapter = gridView.adapter as GridAdapter
                    gridAdapter.updateSelectedPositions(selectedLetters)  // Visually update the cells being swiped over
                }
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                if (swiping) {
                    Log.d("WordSearch", "Action Up: End swipe")
                    swiping = false
                    checkForWordFound() // Check if the selected letters form a word
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isValidSwipe(startX: Int, startY: Int, endX: Int, endY: Int): Boolean {
        val dx = abs(endX - startX)
        val dy = abs(endY - startY)

        // Allow movement if it's in a straight line (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal)
        return (dx == 0 && dy > 0) || (dy == 0 && dx > 0) || (dx == dy)
    }

    private fun updateSelectedLetters(startX: Int, startY: Int, endX: Int, endY: Int) {
        selectedLetters.clear()
        val dx = endX - startX
        val dy = endY - startY
        val steps = maxOf(abs(dx), abs(dy))

        for (i in 0..steps) {
            val x = startX + i * dx / steps
            val y = startY + i * dy / steps
            if (x in 0 until cols && y in 0 until rows) {
                selectedLetters.add(y to x)  // Add the cell to the list of selected letters
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpGrid() {
        clearGrid()
        wordsPlaced.clear()
        hintIndex = 0
        progressBar.progress = 0
        progressText.text = "0/10 words found"

        placeWordsRandomly()
        fillGridWithRandomLetters()

        val gridAdapter = GridAdapter(this, letters, ::handleLetterSelection)
        gridView.numColumns = cols
        gridView.adapter = gridAdapter

        displayWordList()
        startTimer()
    }

    private fun startTimer() {
        timer?.cancel()

        timer = object : CountDownTimer(2 * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val minutesRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 60000
                val secondsRemaining = (millisUntilFinished % 60000) / 1000
                timerText.text = "Time: $minutesRemaining:${String.format("%02d", secondsRemaining)}"
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                timerText.text = "Time's Up!"
                showRoundMessage(success = false)
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun showRoundMessage(success: Boolean) {
        val successMessages = listOf("Well done!", "Good job!", "Fantastic!", "Amazing job!")
        val failureMessages = listOf("Better luck next time!", "So close!", "Almost there!", "Don't give up!")

        val message = if (success) {
            successMessages.random()
        } else {
            failureMessages.random()
        }

        roundMessage.text = message
        roundMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        roundMessage.postDelayed({
            roundMessage.visibility = View.GONE
            setUpGrid()
        }, 5000)
    }

    private fun clearGrid() {
        for (i in 0 until rows) {
            for (j in 0 until cols) {
                letters[i][j] = ' '
            }
        }
        foundWords.clear()
        selectedLetters.clear()
    }

    private fun placeWordsRandomly() {
        val wordsToPlace = wordsToFind.shuffled().take(10)
        for (word in wordsToPlace) {
            var placed = false
            while (!placed) {
                placed = tryPlaceWord(word)
            }
            wordsPlaced.add(word)
        }
    }

    private fun tryPlaceWord(word: String): Boolean {
        val directions = listOf("HORIZONTAL", "VERTICAL", "DIAGONAL")
        val direction = directions.random()

        val rowStart = Random.nextInt(rows)
        val colStart = Random.nextInt(cols)

        when (direction) {
            "HORIZONTAL" -> if (colStart + word.length <= cols) {
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    if (letters[rowStart][colStart + i] != ' ') return false
                }
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    letters[rowStart][colStart + i] = word[i]
                }
                return true
            }

            "VERTICAL" -> if (rowStart + word.length <= rows) {
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    if (letters[rowStart + i][colStart] != ' ') return false
                }
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    letters[rowStart + i][colStart] = word[i]
                }
                return true
            }

            "DIAGONAL" -> if (rowStart + word.length <= rows && colStart + word.length <= cols) {
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    if (letters[rowStart + i][colStart + i] != ' ') return false
                }
                for (i in word.indices) {
                    letters[rowStart + i][colStart + i] = word[i]
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun fillGridWithRandomLetters() {
        for (i in 0 until rows) {
            for (j in 0 until cols) {
                if (letters[i][j] == ' ') {
                    letters[i][j] = ('A'..'Z').random()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun displayWordList() {
        wordListColumn1.text = createStyledWordList(wordsPlaced.take(5))
        wordListColumn2.text = createStyledWordList(wordsPlaced.drop(5).take(5))
    }

    private fun createStyledWordList(words: List<String>): SpannableString {
        val wordList = words.joinToString("\n")
        val spannableString = SpannableString(wordList)

        var startIndex = 0
        for (word in words) {
            val endIndex = startIndex + word.length
            if (foundWords.contains(word)) {
                spannableString.setSpan(StrikethroughSpan(), startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            }
            startIndex = endIndex + 1
        }

        return spannableString
    }

    private fun provideHint() {
        while (hintIndex < wordsPlaced.size && foundWords.contains(wordsPlaced[hintIndex])) {
            hintIndex++
        }

        if (hintIndex < wordsPlaced.size) {
            val wordToHint = wordsPlaced[hintIndex]
            highlightWord(wordToHint)
            hintIndex++
        }
    }

    private fun highlightWord(word: String) {
        val positions = getWordPositions(word)
        if (positions.isNotEmpty()) {
            val gridAdapter = gridView.adapter as GridAdapter
            gridAdapter.updateHighlightedWords(listOf(positions))
        }
    }

    private fun handleLetterSelection(row: Int, col: Int) {
        val position = row to col

        if (selectedLetters.contains(position)) {
            selectedLetters.remove(position)
        } else {
            selectedLetters.add(position)
        }

        val gridAdapter = gridView.adapter as GridAdapter
        gridAdapter.updateSelectedPositions(selectedLetters)

        checkForWordFound()
    }

    private fun checkForWordFound() {
        val selectedWord = getSelectedWordFromPositions()

        if (wordsPlaced.contains(selectedWord) && !foundWords.contains(selectedWord)) {
            foundWords.add(selectedWord)
            updateGridHighlights()
            displayWordList()
            selectedLetters.clear()

            progressBar.progress = foundWords.size
            progressText.text = "${foundWords.size}/10 words found"

            if (foundWords.size == 10) {
                timer?.cancel()
                showRoundMessage(success = true)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSelectedWordFromPositions(): String {
        val sortedPositions = selectedLetters.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.first }, { it.second }))
        return sortedPositions.joinToString("") { (row, col) -> letters[row][col].toString() }
    }

    private fun updateGridHighlights() {
        val gridAdapter = gridView.adapter as GridAdapter
        val allHighlightedPositions = mutableListOf<List<Pair<Int, Int>>>()

        for (word in foundWords) {
            val wordPositions = getWordPositions(word)
            if (wordPositions.isNotEmpty()) {
                allHighlightedPositions.add(wordPositions)
            }
        }

        gridAdapter.updateHighlightedWords(allHighlightedPositions)
    }

    private fun getWordPositions(word: String): List<Pair<Int, Int>> {
        for (i in 0 until rows) {
            for (j in 0 until cols) {
                if (letters[i][j] == word[0]) {
                    val horizontalPositions = checkHorizontal(i, j, word)
                    if (horizontalPositions.isNotEmpty()) return horizontalPositions

                    val verticalPositions = checkVertical(i, j, word)
                    if (verticalPositions.isNotEmpty()) return verticalPositions

                    val diagonalPositions = checkDiagonal(i, j, word)
                    if (diagonalPositions.isNotEmpty()) return diagonalPositions
                }
            }
        }
        return emptyList()
    }

    private fun checkHorizontal(row: Int, col: Int, word: String): List<Pair<Int, Int>> {
        if (col + word.length > cols) return emptyList()
        return word.indices.map { row to (col + it) }
            .takeIf { positions -> positions.all { (r, c) -> letters[r][c] == word[positions.indexOf(r to c)] } }
            ?: emptyList()
    }

    private fun checkVertical(row: Int, col: Int, word: String): List<Pair<Int, Int>> {
        if (row + word.length > rows) return emptyList()
        return word.indices.map { (row + it) to col }
            .takeIf { positions -> positions.all { (r, c) -> letters[r][c] == word[positions.indexOf(r to c)] } }
            ?: emptyList()
    }

    private fun checkDiagonal(row: Int, col: Int, word: String): List<Pair<Int, Int>> {
        if (row + word.length > rows || col + word.length > cols) return emptyList()
        return word.indices.map { (row + it) to (col + it) }
            .takeIf { positions -> positions.all { (r, c) -> letters[r][c] == word[positions.indexOf(r to c)] } }
            ?: emptyList()
    }
}


You might want to add a relevant tag in addition to kotlin, to indicate which UI framework you're using. Having just the kotlin tag brings your question to the attention of all Kotlin developers, many of whom develop on back-end servers and have no idea what "Bundle", and "enableEdgeToEdge" etc. are.
